# UITableView Data Based on Previous View

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, view, tableview, grouped-table

I'm currently working on the settings section of my iPhone app, and I just came to realization that if each page in the settings had it's own view and .h + .m, that would be A LOT of unnecessary code and views.  So I came up with the conclusion that I would simply have only one type of detail view that would change depending on the row in a table view  that the user selected.  However... I'm kind of struggling.

The Setup:

- For the main settings view, I want it to be a grouped table view with multiple groups and rows.
- For the settings detail view, I also want it to be a grouped table view with multiple groups and rows (that is where it gets confusing).

I have seen simple things such as images and labels depend on the previous view, but not grouped table view structures. Is it possible to complete what I want without tons of views or 'if' statements? Any sort of help is apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do two things (considering you have a setting view controller and a detail view controller)...

First, when a user selects a row in the setting view controller, you have to set the setting you'll be editing in the detail view controller. That is....

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [self.detailViewCtrl setSetting:[self.settings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewCtrl];
}
```

In your detail view, you'll have to modify the following method to render your table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // ... do something with the self.setting
}
```

And you can't forget to reload the table:

```
- (void)setSetting:(id)newSetting {
  if (setting != newSetting) {
    [setting release];
    setting = [newSetting retain];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
  }
}
```

This is assuming the following:

- Your first view has the 'detailViewCtrl' property instantiated
- Your first view has an NSArray of settings property called 'settings'
- Your detail view has a 'setting' property
- Your detail view controller know what to do with its 'setting' property

Comment: Z Thanks for the response, but there are some areas of iPhone dev I'm still a little un-clear on.  By a property for settings, do you mean a string? Would I also have to define setting and newSetting as strings?

Comment: @Andy, the 'setting' should be a custom object (or a settings bundle object?). I'm not sure what properties it would have but it may be something like this: Setting(name, type, value, options). You should consider how you will be loading/storing your settings and how you're going to be manipulating them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's certainly possible. Apple essentially does this with the [Settings bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Introduction/Introduction.html) and its configuration through a plist file.

What you want to write is a generic table view controller that loads its configuration and contents from an external source (one or more plist files are a very good choice for this). It's not very hard to do, at least as long as the actions your table view executes (e.g. when the user taps a cell) are well-defined and easy to encode in a config file. For example: actions like "open a new page with this config" or "save this value under this key to the user defaults" are simple to set up while something like "have the user take a picture with the camera, then let them crop it to their liking and upload it to Twitter" is harder.

Comment: Thanks for the response, though I would not want to use the Settings Bundle because it would defeat the point of the app.

Comment: I understand that. But the way the Settings bundle uses its plist config file could show you a possible way to implement this functionality yourself.